# Microservices dependence management - Governance or Domain Driven Design?

Tags: domain-driven-design, dependency-management, microservices, soa-governance

**Background**: an international company with a federation model is transforming into Microservices due to chronic Monolithic pain. Autonomous teams with quick deployment is highly desirable. In spite of theory, services are indeed dependent on each other for higher functionality, but are autonomous (independently developed and deployed). Since this is a federation model and decentralized control, we cannot impose strict rules - just like the UN. Without a governance platform that will manage dependencies else due to the multiple versions in production in different countries, we foresee uncontrollable chaos.

Let's call set of Microservices that needs to collaborate a "Compatibility Set". A service can be deployed but may not satisfy the higher functionality in its Compatibility Set.  For example MicroService A-4.3 is fully autonomous, deployed and working perfectly. However to satisfy BusinessFunctionality 8.6 it must work together with MicroService B-5.4 and MicroService C-2.9. Together (A-4.3 , B-5.4 and C-2.9) they form a "Compatibility Set"

There are two approaches to this dilemma. Microservice in real life where the rubber hits the road and the learning from experience begins...

**Approach 1) Governance Platform**

*Rationale*: Federal model in an International company in 100+ countries. Which means Central IT can lay down the model but individual countries can choose their own destiny - and they frequently do. It frequently devolves to chaos and the Central IT team is on the hook. DDD is the solution for an ideal world where version inconsistencies do not derail functionality like releasing services which do not fit into the Compatibility set, individually blameless but together they fall apart or result in flawed or inconsistent functionality.

- There is no homogeneity, there isn't even standardization of terminology
- Developers are mixed skill, many junior, and many learning reactive programming and cloud native technologies
- Bounded Context heavily depends on Shared Vocabulary and it can get subtle, but this is impossible to enforce and naive to assume in an International, mixed skill, fragmented scenario with multiple versions running
- Standardization on a Single Business Model is not realistic in such a heterogeneous system (but ideal)

How what is Central IT to do when they're held responsible for this Chaos?

*Enforce a Governance Platform*
Create a Microservices governance system or framework to enforce dependency management. It verifies and enforces at design and run time dependencies on a particular Microservice through a manifest and performs some checks and balances to verify the service implementations being offered - the  "Compatibility Set".

**Approach 2)  Domain Driven Design (DDD)**
DDD is about modelling domains that are constantly evolving, where domain experts (typically a business stakeholder, or perhaps an analyst) will work alongside developers to design the system. Within each domain, a ubiquitous language is formed, such that within that context, the same word always means the same thing. An important thing to realise is that in one part of your system, “Order” might mean one thing, it might mean for example a list of products. In another part of your system, “Order” might mean something else, it might mean a financial transaction that happened. This is where the model you describe can fall down, if my service needs to get a list of orders, perhaps there is a capability out there that supplies a list of orders, but which orders are they? The list of products or the financial transaction? Trying to coordinate as many developers as you have to all use the same language here is an impossible task that is doomed to fail.

In DDD, rather than trying to manage this at a system level and force every service to use the same definition of Order, DDD embraces the inherent complexity in coordinating very large deployments with huge numbers of developers involved, and allows each team to work independently, coordinating with other teams as needed, not through some centralised dependency management system. The term used in DDD is bounded contexts, where in one context, Order means one thing, and in another bounded context, Order can mean another thing. These contexts can function truly autonomously – you describe your services as being autonomous, but if they have to match their definition of order with the entire system by registering and supplied dependencies to a central registry, then really they are tightly coupled to the rest of the system and what it considers an order to be – you end up with all the painful coupling of a monolith, with all the pain of building a distributed system, and you won’t realise many of the benefits of microservices if you try to take this approach.

So a DDD based approach doesn’t ever try to take a heavy handed approach of enforcing dependencies or capabilities at the system level, rather, it allows individual teams to work without needing central coordination, if Service A needs to interact with Service B, then the team who manages Service A will work with the team that manages service B, they can build an interface between their bounded contexts, and come to an agreement on language for that interface. It is up to these teams to manage their dependencies with each other, at the system level things can remain quite opaque / unenforced.

Too often we see people implement “Microservices” but end up with a system that is just as, if not more inflexible, and often more fragile, than a monolith. Also called a "Minilith" or "Monolith 2.0" Microservices require a complete rethink of architecture and software development processes, and require not just allowing services to be autonomous and independently managed, but also for teams to be independent, not centrally managed. Centralising the management of dependencies and capabilities in a system is likely to be an inhibitor to successfully building a microservice based system.

**Intelligent and Pragmatic comments invited...**

Approach 1 (Governance) is pragmatic and tactical and intended to solve very real challenges. Question is - will it undermine the long term strategic DDD model of the Enterprise?

Approach 2 (DDD) is ideal and aspirational but doesn't address the very real challenges that we have to deal with right now.

Opinions? Thought? Comments?

Comment: I'm not sure the dichotomy is valid. DDD isn't prescriptive about ways in which teams should coordinate, it merely mentions a number of them. Some instances of *Conformist* as described in DDD might be a good match for what you define as "governance platform".

Answer (score 1):

I've seen multi-national companies try to cooperate on a project (or be controlled from a central IT team) and it's a nightmare.  This response is highly subjective to what I've personally read and seen, so it's just my opinion, it's probably not everyone's opinion.  Generally broad questions aren't encouraged on Stack Overflow as they attract highly opinionated answers.

I'd say DDD probably isn't the answer.  You'd need a large number of a developers to buy into the DDD idea.  If you don't have that buy-in then (unless you have a team of exceptionally self-motivated people) you'll see the developers try to build the new system on-top of the existing database.

I'd also argue that [microservices aren't the answer](https://plainoldobjects.com/2016/03/01/thoughts-on-if-you-cant-build-a-well-structured-monolith-what-makes-you-think-microservices-is-the-answer/).  Companies that have used microservices to their advantage are essentially using them to compartmentalise their code into small, stacks of individually running services/apps that each do a single job.  These microservices ([from the success stories I've seen](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/12/microservices-spotify)) tend to be loosely coupled.  I imagine that if you have a large number of services that are highly coupled, then you've still got the spaghetti aspects of a monolith, but one that's [spread out over a network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing).

It sounds like you just need a well architected system, designed to your specific needs.  I agree that using DDD would be great, but is it a realistic goal across a multi-national project?

Answer (score 1):

I also dealt with the problem described in the question. And I came up with an approach in which I use API-definitions like OpenAPI-definitions to check compatibility between two services. The API-definitions must be attached as metadata to each service and therefore it is possible to do the check at run and design time. Important is that the API-definitions are part of the metadata as well when the API is offered and when the API is used. With tools like Swagger-Diff or OpenAPI-Diff it is possible to do the compatibility-check automated.